# Cycles Not Baking Emission Material Properly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, lighting

I’m trying to bake my neon sign but it’s not working. The emission is off, I think it’s because of my material set up. My emission material is connected to a multiply, colorramp and layer weight nodes (please see image below) This gives that neon / glow looking effect. Do certain materials not work for cycles rendering?

[image: The material setup]

[image: What the render looks like]

[image: How the bake ended up looking like]

Thanks!